# jQuery show div on clicking textarea

Tags: jquery

I have following code:

```
<div class="question">
 <span class="text_area>
  <textarea name="text1" id="response1" rows="3" cols="50"/>
 </span>
<div>
<div class="questionRespond">
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk_1"/>
  <span>
   <input class="questionbutton" id=send1Button/>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="question">
 <span class="text_area>
  <textarea name="text1" id="response1" rows="3" cols="50"/>
 </span>
<div>
<div class="questionRespond">
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk_2"/>
  <span>
   <input class="questionbutton" id=send1Button/>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="question">
 <span class="text_area>
  <textarea name="text2" id="response3" rows="3" cols="50"/>
 </span>
<div>
<div class="questionRespond">
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk_3"/>
  <span>
   <input class="questionbutton" id=send3Button/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Basically it is texarea and below that there is a checkbox and button. I want the checkbox and button to only show when user click on textarea. Can this be done in jQuery?

Comment: Yes, this can be done in jQuery.

Comment: why not.... even by javascript you can do it... jquery is far more efficient to javascript but for this simple thing it' not needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure that the elements which should be hidden are initially hidden since nobody did yet click the textarea, obviously. Then you'd want to attach a click handler to all of the textareas with show the checkboxes and buttons.

```
// Initially hide controls (should be better done without JavaScript)
jQuery('.questionRespond').hide();

// Handle the clicks
jQuery('.question textarea').click(function(){
    // this points to the textarea, look for the question div first, then the following response controls
    var respondControls = jQuery(this).closest('.question').next();
    respondControls.show();
});
```

Remember to fix your HTML since you're repeating identifiers and omitting quotes.

Comment: @Augustus thanks for explaining one question i have. jQuery(this) has? Does it contain id of textarea?

Comment: //Using Find worked for me. Maybe it will help someone else too.
    $(this).closest(".question").find(".questionRespond").show();

Comment: `this` is a reference to the click textarea (Element node). Encapsulating it in the jQuery call give an object with additional functions (still representing the clicked textarea). We need this to call `closest` on it which finds the nearest parent that contains the textarea. Consequently `jQuery(this).closest('.question')` gives the question div holding to the clicked textarea. `next()` gets the response div which directly follows the question.

I don't get how `find` can work as intended given the HTML structure from the question.

Answer (score 0):

initially hide the questionRespond class with css then following jquery will show the div

```
    $('.text_area textarea').click(function(){
         $(this).closest('.question').next().show();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".questionRespond").hide();

  $("textarea").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){

        var qrcontainer = $(this).closest(".question").next(".questionRespond");
        qrcontainer.show();


   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use focus

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.questionRespond').hide();

$('textarea').focus(function(){
   $(this).closest('div. question').next('div.questionRespond').show();
}
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// make questionRespond display:none
<div class="questionRespond" style="display:none">

// this will show the divs on clicking textarea
$('textarea').focus(function(){

      jQuery(this).closest('.question').find('.questionRespond').show();       
})


// this function will hide divs when you leave that textarea
$('textarea').blur(function(){

      jQuery(this).closest('.question').find('.questionRespond').hide();       
})
```